# handle {_locale} prefixes on Silex with the TranslationServiceProvider

Tags: php, symfony, translation, silex

I am trying to make the website I am working on, translatable. As I am using Silex, I chose the TranslationServiceProvider which is working nicely.

Here is my code from app.php :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale' => 'en',
    'locale_fallback' => array('en'),
));
$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/locales/en.yml', 'en');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/locales/fr.yml', 'fr');

    return $translator;
}));
```

And here is the beginning of my router (routes.php) :

```
// Home page
$app->get('/', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home');

// View an existing news
$app->get('/news/{id}', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::newsAction")->bind('newsAction');

// Activities page
$app->get('/activities', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::activitiesAction")->bind('activities');

// View an existing activity
$app->get('/activity/{id}', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::activityAction")->bind('activityAction');
```

The problem is that I don't know how to prefix all my routes with {_locale}. If I do it, the unprefixed URL leads to a 404 error.

I saw this solution for Symfony :

```
oc_platform:
    resource: "@OCPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/platform
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr
```

But it requires a .yml router and I don't know if it works the same way with Silex (I've never used .yml files before now so I am kind of lost).

How can I prefix my routes without having to rewrite everything (which would be very ugly) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add _locale parameter in your routes

`$app->get('/{_locale}/', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home')->assert('_locale', 'en|fr');`

or

`$app->get('/{_locale}/news/{id}', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::newsAction")->bind('newsAction')->assert('_locale', 'en|fr');`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but when the link leads to '/' or '/news/{id}', there is no route available. I want, for example, to have '/news/6' equivalent to '/en/news/6' because the default language is English.

Comment: make 2 routes: with locale and without locale

Comment: ex: `$app->get('/{_locale}/', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home')->assert('_locale', 'en|fr'); $app->get('/', "FarmaDubno\Controller\HomeController::indexAction")->bind('homewl');`

Comment: I thought of that solution, but it's code duplication. I really don't like it and it asks me to change everything in my application. Isn't there any better solution ? Also, I would need to know how to get this {_locale} variable in the controller (to know where to redirect).

Comment: I don't know if it is good idea, but you can make routes like
`$app->get('/{locale}hello', function(Request $request) {
    return 'Hello! '.$request->getLocale();
})
    ->bind('hello')
    ->assert('locale', '((en|fr)/)?')
;`.

Comment: And define locale in application listener, something like
`$application['dispatcher']->addListener(
    KernelEvents::REQUEST,
    function($event) use ($application) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale = $request->get('locale');
        if (!empty($locale)) {
                $locale = \trim($locale, '\\/');
                $request->attributes->set('_locale', $locale);
                if ($locale != 'en') $application['locale_url'] = $locale.'/';
        } else {
                $application['locale_url'] = '';
        }
    },
    32
);`.

Comment: Also this will cause problems with urls, parameter locale will be required, in twig something like {{ path('hello', {'locale':app.locale_url}) }}

Comment: You can get locale from request $request->getLocale(). Add request as parameter to you controller function xxx(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)