# Automatic localization from browser or session var

Tags: php, symfony, localization, routes

I'm using symfony2.8. I made translation yaml files for couple lang (en|de|cz). Then I added requirements to routing:

**(global) *app\config\routing.yml***

```
comflex_w2:
    resource: "@ComflexW2Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    defaults: { _controller: ComflexW2Bundle:Home:index, _locale: en } 
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de|cz
```

**and inside bundle *src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Resources\config\routing.yml***

```
comflex_w2_home:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: ComflexW2Bundle:Home:index}


comflex_w2_login_check:
    path: /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: ComflexW2Bundle:User:authorization }
```

Now, when I go to **host/web/app_dev.php/de** or **.../en**, or **.../cz** then transations are worked, but when request doesn't contain **locale** like **host/web/app_dev.php**, then I get

> "No route found for "GET /" with 404 error

How to set locale in url automatically from session files (only after user logged) or from browser local or finally set as en when nobody is logged.

I found entry **default_locale:  "%locale%"** in ***app\config\config.yml*** but i have no idea how it's work and where **"%locale%** set is.

Comment: You get error because _locale is required in route `_locale: en|de|cz`. This parameter than defines locale in your application. Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34109527/5298034, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route defined for '/', that is the reason why you get this error.

When you are working with locale prefixes in your urls, it's always a good idea to redirect the user from / to a locale-prefixed url, e.g. /en/.

You should add a controller that matches / and redirects to the localized home url:

```
public function redirectAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->getPreferredLanguage(['en', 'de', 'cz']);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('comflex_w2_home', ['_locale' => $locale], 301);
}
```